# In Kotlin, how to refactor "if else" and use "when" instead of it with equals ignore case comparison?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, equals

I want to refactor this code for using "when" instead of "if else". How can I use Kotlin's when(char) with ignore case for my situation?

```
    if(char.equals("A", true))
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade1))
    else if(char.equals("B", true))
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade2))
    else if(char.equals("C", true))
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade3))
    else if(char.equals("D", true))
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade4))
    else if(char.equals("E", true))
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade5))
    else if(char.equals("F", true))
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade6))
    ...
    else if(char.equals("Z", true))
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade26))
    else
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade27))
```

Please let me know if there is a way to do this in a good way.

Comment: Hover the cursor over the `if` keyword and you will notice a yellow bulb icon on the left side.  Expand the yellow icon and you will see refractor option to change `if` to `when`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```kotlin
val ch = 'A'
val src = when (ch.toUpperCase()) {
    'A' -> R.color.colorBgShade1
    'B' -> R.color.colorBgShade2
    // ...
    'Z' -> R.color.colorBgShade26
    else -> R.color.colorBgShade27
}
background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, src))
```

But using `Map` is always a better way for such problem.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler way to implement what you need is:

```kotlin
val colorMap = mapOf (
    'A' to R.color.colorBgShade1,
    'B' to R.color.colorBgShade2,
    ...
    ...
)

val char = 'G'
val bgColor = colorMap[char] ?: R.color.colorBgShade27
background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, bgColor)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need.

```
val char = "G"
when {
    char.equals("A", true) -> {
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade1))
    }
    char.equals("B", true) -> {
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade2))
    }
    char.equals("C", true) -> {
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade3))
    }
    char.equals("D", true) -> {
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade4))
    }
    char.equals("E", true) -> {
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade5))
    }
    char.equals("F", true) -> {
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade6))
    }
    char.equals("Z", true) -> {
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade26))
    }
    else -> {
        background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBgShade27))
    }
}
```

But the best way is that you should do it like this.

```
data class Alpha(val alpha:String , val color: Int)

fun generateData() {
    val listAlpha = arrayListOf<Alpha>()
    listAlpha.add(Alpha("A", R.color.colorBgShade1))
    listAlpha.add(Alpha("B", R.color.colorBgShade2))
    listAlpha.add(Alpha("C", R.color.colorBgShade3))
    listAlpha.add(Alpha("D", R.color.colorBgShade4))

    var char = "D"
    val alphaFindResult = listAlpha.single { it.alpha.equals(char, true) }
    background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, alphaFindResult.color))
}
```